# SPFx Webpart data is not getting reflected

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

i have created an SPFx webpart using the React and used in a SharePoint online solution. multiple page have the same webpart with different set of data, while navigating from one page to another data is not getting refreshed. after reload the page or open in a new tab is working fine.

i have debugged and couldn't find solution for that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any SharePoint Online settings or configurations that might be affecting how data is cached or loaded in your web part.

If you've tried these steps and the issue persists, providing specific code snippets related to data fetching and updating would be helpful in diagnosing the problem further.